# Is there a way to publish a page in the past in Wagtail CMS?

Tags: django, wagtail

In Wagtail CMS you can publish pages and even set schedules. It seems that you can't publish pages in the past.

When I set a schedule in the past (e.g. 01/01/2022) and publish the page, I don't get the expected behaviour.

When now accessing the pages property (first_published_at & last_published_at), I don't get 01/01/2022, but the date and time I published the date.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Page.go_live_at` is the field affected by the scheduled publishing options, and should correctly reflect dates set in the past. `first_published_at` and `last_published_at` indicate the actual times the page was published - this is necessary to ensure the correct behaviour of features like moderation workflows (where there could be a delay before the moderator approves the page, meaning that it's published later than the original page author intended.)

Comment: Thanks a lot @gasman! Apparently I overlooked this attribute when tinkering in the shell.